# Using WHERE IN and WHERE NOT IN in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use WHERE IN and WHERE NOT IN in mysql query?

I have tried using them in one query but with wrong results. So i want to ask is theoretically possible to exclude some results with NOT IN and IN statement?

EDIT 1: i am using statements on the same column.

Comment: Definitely possible... can you show us the query?  Remember, you have to do `WHERE Column IN (Something) AND Column NOT IN (Something)` and **not** `WHERE Column IN (Something) AND NOT IN (Something)` (i.e., you have to specify the column each time, you cant implicitly say that you are using the same column)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely *possible*, but <s>unless you're using them with different columns,</s> it doesn't make a lot of sense unless you don't control the sets involved. <s>If you're using them with different columns, it can make perfect sense.</s>

E.g., this doesn't make sense most of the time:

```
WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3) AND A NOT IN (4, 5, 6)
```

...because if `A` is in `1, 2, 3` it is, by definition, not in `4, 5, 6`. The second part is redundant. Just

```
WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3)
```

is all you need. But you **can** do (for instance, when you don't know what the sets are, you're getting them from some other source):

```
WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3) AND A NOT IN (3, 4, 5)
```

that will boil down to:

```
WHERE A IN (1, 2)
```

<s>But this can make sense:</s>

```
WHERE A IN (1, 2, 3) AND B NOT IN (4, 5, 6)
```

*(The strikeout is because of the edit to the question.)*

Comment: Yep, this makes sense and definitely works,  I have just tested it. You guessed my case "(for instance, when you don't know what the sets are, you're getting them from some other source)". This is only the part of my query, but now i  have a clue what is wrong. Thanks T.J. Crowder

Comment: What happens if i have a table that has multiple rows with the same data for column A and different for column B. So basically it is a pivot table for many to many relation. I will give an example. I have a table with video ids and every video has multiple categories. When i use the above query, and i want to do WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND category_id NOT IN (3, 4, 5) i only exclude that one row which has category_id=3. But if that video has another category it is going to get into my result set and that is what i don't want to happen. Do you maybe have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: @happy_fist: I think you'll want to post a new question giving the details of the relations, etc., and posing that question. It sounds like you *might* want `SELECT video_id FROM videoCategories WHERE category_id IN (1, 2, 3) AND video_id NOT IN (SELECT video_ID FROM videoCategories WHERE category_id IN (4, 5, 6))` which grabs videos with 1, 2, or 3 but not if they also have 4, 5, or 6, but it depends a **lot** on what end result you want, what the tables look like, etc...

Comment: That is what i was looking for. Tested it couple of times, and it worked. If you think this question can help somebody or something like that, i can post a new question considering this. What do you say?

Comment: @happy_fist: Nah, probably no need. Glad I guessed right! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM someTable
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) AND name NOT IN ('foo','bar','baz');
```